# Store Subsequences in list of lists using recursion in python

Tags: python-3.x, recursion, subsequence

This may sound very simple, I tried searching for the solution but couldn't find it hence posting the question. Appreciate the help, Thanks in advance.

I am trying to print all the subsequences of a given list/string in python using recursion.
Below is the output I expect:

Given Input list : `[1,3,2]`
Output List : `[[],[1],[3],[2],[1,2],[1,3],[3,2],[1,3,2]]`

This is what I have tried:

```
def printSubsequences(ind,ans,l,n):
    final_ans = []
    if ind == n:
        return ans
    else:
        ans.append(l[ind])
        final_ans.extend(printSubsequences(ind+1,ans,l,n))
        
        ans.pop()
        
        final_ans.extend(printSubsequences(ind+1,ans,l,n))
        return final_ans
       
print(printSubsequences(0,[],[1,3,2],3))

Output of above code: [1, 3, 2, 1, 3, 1, 2, 1, 3, 2, 3, 2]
```

The output is correct partially as It does not contain `[]` (empty subset), but I want it in specified format as aforementioned. I also tried `append` method but that is giving `Output : [[[[], []], [[], []]], [[[], []], [[], []]]]`.

I don't understand what I am doing wrong here, Can someone explain - Why `append` is failing and `extend` is working, and How can I get my desired output ?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

You have run into this classic python trap:

- [List of lists changes reflected across sublists unexpectedly](https://stackoverflow.com/questions/240178/list-of-lists-changes-reflected-across-sublists-unexpectedly)

When you append `ans` to the list of results, it's always a reference to the same list `ans`, not a copy. So when you call `ans.pop()`, you erase the last element of that list, and it is removed in all subsequences. Try for instance this code:

```py
a = [2]
b = [a, a, a]
print(b) # [[2], [2], [2]]
a.pop()
print(b) # [[], [], []]
```

The workaround is to adopt a more functional style, never modifying the `ans` list in-place, and rather building a new list when needed for the recursive calls:

```py
def subsequences(ind,ans,l,n):
    final_ans = []
    if ind == n:
        return [ans]
    else:
        final_ans.extend(subsequences(ind+1,ans + [l[ind]],l,n))
        final_ans.extend(subsequences(ind+1,ans,l,n))
        return final_ans

>>> subsequences(0, [], [1,2,3], 3)
[[1, 2, 3], [1, 2], [1, 3], [1], [2, 3], [2], [3], []]
```

Notable modifications:

- I renamed the function `subsequences` rather than `printSubsequences`, since it doesn't print;
- I fixed the base case which should be `return [ans]`, not `return ans`;
- I replaced the calls to `ans.append` and `ans.pop` with `+` in the recursive calls.

Comment: Thank you, this worked ! I understood now. The pop() was removing all the previous references.